# Linear Transfomations

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking for some help with the following two questions. I believe I did the first one correct but not quite sure how to do the second one.

> 1) Let $T :\Bbb R^2 \to  \Bbb R^2 $ so $$
> x=\begin{bmatrix}
> x\\  
> y
> \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}  
> 3x-y\\  
> 4x+5y
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$ Show that $T$ is a linear transformation.

Solution

So $$
T(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\  
y
\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}  
3x-y\\  
4x+5y
\end{bmatrix}$$ = $$
A(\begin{bmatrix}
x\\  
y
\end{bmatrix}) -> T = T_A $$ with $$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1  
\\ 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix} $$. So $T$ Is a linear transformation.

---

Number 2 is the one I am having trouble with and looking to get a explanation of.

> 2)  Show that the function $T : R^3 -> R $ defined by $$ T(x)= det
> (\begin{bmatrix}
> x_1&1&4  
> \\ x_2&2&5  
> \\ x_3&3&6
> \end{bmatrix}) $$ where  $$ x=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> x_1  
> \\x_2  
> \\ x_3  
> \end{bmatrix} $$, is a linear transformation

Comment: Expand the determinant to obtain a linear expression.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Here's another way of looking at $T(x)$:
$$T(x)=x_1\left\lvert\begin{matrix} 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 6\end{matrix}\right\rvert-x_2\left\lvert\begin{matrix} 1 & 4 \\ 3 & 6\end{matrix}\right\rvert+x_3\left\lvert\begin{matrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 5\end{matrix}\right\rvert$$
$$T(x)=-3x_1+6x_2-3x_3$$
$$T(x)=[\begin{matrix}-3 & 6 & -3\end{matrix}]x$$

Comment: so then where do I go from there?

Comment: We have now shown that $T(x)$ is just multiplying $x$ by the matrix $[\begin{matrix}-3 & 6 & -3\end{matrix}]$ on the left. Therefore, since this is just a matrix multiplication, it must be a linear transformation.

Comment: okay I see what you are saying, so now showing that $T(x)$ is just multiplying x by the matrix -3 6 -3, we can see that this matrix is a linear transformation

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second question is easier if you first expand the determinant to rewrite the transformation as 
$$
T(x) = -3x_1 + 6x_2 - 3x_3 = \pmatrix{-3&6&-3}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3}
$$
incidentally: if you know what *cross-products* are, then $(-3,6,-3) = (1,2,3)\times (4,5,6)$.

Comment: The third component should be $-3$, not $-1$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak indeed, $2 \times 4 \neq 6$.  Silly mistake

Comment: where do I go from there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show two things.

1. $T(x+y) = T(x) +T(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$
2. $T(\alpha x) = \alpha T(x)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$

If you cant see how to proceed (and this goes for any map you are trying to show is a linear transformation) then evaluate the lhs of (1), then evaluate the rhs of (1) then you rearrange one of these answers to get the other. Then do the same for (2). So for your example

lhs of (1) is $(x_{1}+y_{1})(2.6-3.5)-(x_{2}+y_{2})(1.6-3.4)+(x_{3}+y_{3})(1.5-4.2)$

rhs of (1) is $\{(x_{1})(2.6-3.5)-(x_{2})(1.6-3.4)+(x_{3})(1.5-4.2)\}+\{ (y_{1})(2.6-3.5)-(y_{2})(1.6-3.4)+(y_{3})(1.5-4.2)\}$

which you can you rearrange to be equal to lhs.

Similarly for (2).

Quite often you can reduce your work because your map is described in terms of other mathematical objects (such as matrices or determinates or permutations and so on) and you can use properties and results/facts of these other objects (like for matrices $A(B+C)=AB + AC$ where the product and sums are defined). This gives a "slicker" proof. However if you can not "see" a slick way you can always start as described above.